# Open imagePickerController from button in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a `UITableViewCell` that contains a `UIImage` and a `UIButton`. I am trying to implement functionality where when the button is tapped a `imagePickerController` is called and the picture taken is placed in that `UITableViewCell's` `UIImage`. I tried using a tutorial on creating a protocol but I can't seem to get it to work at all.

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageFound: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOutlet: UIButton!

    @IBAction func tappedCamera(_ sender: UIButton) {
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }   
}
```

This is my UIViewController code:

```
import UIKit

class SoloPlayListViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, 
UITableViewDataSource, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate {

var objects = ["cup", "phone", "shoe", "tv"]
var imagePicker : UIImagePickerController?
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var tempImage : UIImage?

@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()

}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return objects.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CustomTableViewCell

    return cell
}

}
```

EDIT:

I now have the camera rendering but I am still struggling with how to access the image chosen and assign that to the `UIImageView` in my cell. I tried the following, including attempting to reload the data:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -
> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomTableViewCell", owner: self, 
options: nil)?.first as! CustomTableViewCell

    cell.buttonTouchedClosure = { [weak self] in

            self?.imagePicker!.sourceType = .camera
            self?.present((self?.imagePicker)!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    cell.imageFound.image = tempImage

    return cell
}

func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {

            tempImage = pickedImage
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        }
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a closure for your button action, and in your `tappedCamera` IBAction call this closure

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var imageFound: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet weak var buttonOutlet: UIButton!

    var buttonTouchedClosure : (()->Void)? //closure

    @IBAction func tappedCamera(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.buttonTouchedClosure?() //closure execution
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }   
}
```

**Use it**,Then in your cellForRow method you must set up your closure

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CustomTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CustomTableViewCell
    cell.buttonTouchedClosure = { [weak self] in
       debugPrint("Button Touched")
       //Present here your ImagePickerViewController
    }
    return cell
}
```

Comment: What does adding this closure do? Sorry if it's an obvious one I just haven't seen this before.

Comment: You are passing a code block as variable, when you call your closure() then this code block is executed

Comment: So then can I use the UIImagePickerController in the tappedCamera function in my UITableViewCell file?

Comment: check my updated answer, in the Use it section, where i print "Button Touched" you can present your imagePickerViewController

Comment: @mikew for further reference about closures you can google it, here is one https://www.weheartswift.com/closures/

Comment: So my closure should look something like this:  
    `cell.buttonTouchedClosure = { [weak self] in    
                self?.imagePicker!.sourceType = .camera
                self?.present((self?.imagePicker)!, animated: true, completion: nil)`
        }

Comment: I tried to add it inside of the `imagePickerController` but the picture still isnt appearing.

Comment: Should I do that instead of checking it with the `if let pickedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {`

Comment: I mean check that your code enters in you if let and the tableView.reloadData is executed @mikew

Comment: I added a print statement inside the `func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any])` and it doesn't print so it seems that this func is never being executed

Comment: You are missing setup the UIImagePickerViewController delegate = self, add this line `self.imagePicker!.delegate = self` below this line `imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()` in your viewDidLoad, and let me know must work now

Comment: Wow that finally worked! The only other thing is it seems to be putting this image for all the rows instead of just that current row.